# How to skip redundant forward prop during RL training step in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I have a Tensorflow question regarding Reinforcement Learning. I have everything working and training, but there is something that feels redundant. Want to point it out and hear your thoughts:

Lets assume something simple like episodic REINFORCE. Given this standard setup:

`state -> network -> logits`

When I want to train (when episode complete), I need to:

1. pass in an array of states (saved from running the episode) to a TF Placeholder
2. do a forward pass with those saved states to produce logits
3. compute log_probs (using saved array of actions)
4. compute loss (using saved array of advantages)

This works fine. However, what seems redundant is steps 1&2. I'd prefer to calculate log_probs *during* each step of episode *while episode is being run*. This way I don't have to do steps 1,2,3 during training, and forward pass is only performed once (during episode). I'd have my log_probs calculated by the time the episode was over.

However, if I create placeholders for log_probs and advantages, and don't pass in states (for the redundant forward prop), then I don't know how to get TF to know where the variables are for backprop. I get the error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

So my questions are:

1. if I'm passing in states, is it true that forward prop is being run again during training?
2. can I prevent this by my method above, finding some way to tell TF where the gradients are?

In case anyone wants to see actual code (I tried to be clear enough not to need it), [here is a gist of the script in question](https://gist.github.com/keithmgould/dffafe0d7a922f63f1865989c9b776e4)

EDIT: I think the answer has something to do with using `optimzer.compute_gradients` (where I can pass in variables) and `optimizer.apply_gradients`, but not sure how yet...